# iPhone: If user taps a button to load a view, and clicks again fast, they sometimes click a button that hasn't been drawn yet

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Is there some convention I need to follow to avoid this?

I thought maybe I needed to move the frame declarations out of my init functions.

I thought I could also perhaps avoid this by rendering a transparent overlay until the screen has finished loading, and then remove it. But that seems like a hack.

Comment: Here's what I did: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370953](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370953)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your situation, you could disable the UI elements that allow for [user interaction](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/userInteractionEnabled) until the view has completely loaded.

If you're targeting the 3.0 SDK, you can use [UIViewController:isViewLoaded](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController%5FClass/Reference/Reference.html#//apple%5Fref/occ/instm/UIViewController/isViewLoaded) to determine if the view has been loaded.  Once loaded, you can re-enable user interaction on your buttons.