# viewDidAppear and viewWillDisappear not being called in UIViewController

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

I am creating a UIViewController using the nib file ?

I have implemented the following 2 methods

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated

in my view controller, but these methods are not getting called every time ?

What is the error in the code ?

Comment: Without a code sample we can't really say something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you load your viewController, your

```
(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

will not get called.

[Here is one way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370953/) I load viewcontrollers.  As you see, I explicitly call viewDidAppear, viewDidDisappear, etc. myself.

Answer (score 0):

When initializing from a nib, you can use the [`awakeFromNib` method](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSObject_UIKitAdditions/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/awakeFromNib).